# spring mvc upload a file and invoke a invoke a method async

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I got a requirement to upload a file which contain questions, i need to invoke a 3rd party api and get answers for that write it to another file and provide link for user to download it. Problem is that there can be n number of question and user will not wait, instead he can come back later to see if process got finished. I was thinking to upload a file and then invoke a method async but does this method has got any other issues. Please let me know if there is a way to solve this in spring mvc.

Thanks
Nibin Issac

Answer (score 0):

You can call the 3rd Party API async. Try following [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)


This tutorial contains adding support to `async` in project configuration and achieving async outcome through `Future`. Hope this helps.